# Python column checker-comparing 2 fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, attribute-table, table

One problem I am having is the following:

I want to create an automatic program to see how well the automozation has been with comparing the results of 2 columns to each other in the same column.

In python psedocode, it would look like this:

```
rows= "all rows in table X"
row=rows.next()

counter =0
row counter= rows.length()// amount of rows

while row:
         //If the row`s attribute1 and attribute 2 are the same, add 1 to counter...
         if row. Atrribute1 == row.Attribute:
            counter+= counter
            row=rows.next()
         else:
             // Just go on to next row
            row=row.next()

//Give an overall percentage of success
print(counter/row_counter)*100
```

I cannot imagine that this is hard, but I cannot get it to work with the code from research

One of the major problems is  I cannot find a way to compare 2 field to each other. Ive been searching for a while now, but have found that you can see what a field is, but not how to directly call it.

---

Originally this question included the error message below which was addressed by one of the answers:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'searchCursor'

Comment: Please try not to invalidate existing answers by changing the question that you are asking. Here @Geotob has provided a correct answer to your original question and I think should be rewarded.  I am going to edit the original error message back into the bottom of your question but I think it would have been far preferable to Accept the answer, and then write a New Question.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is because the function is called `SearchCursor()`, with capital S and C.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would go about doing this would be something similar to this in the Interactive Window...

```
rowCounter = 0 #used for your row count
comparisonCounter = 0 #used for your not identical count
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("YOURLAYERHERE") #creating the search cursor

for row in rows: #go through the layer's records
  if row.FieldName1 == row.FieldName2: #These are your field names
  #you can also use row.getValue("FieldName") to get the value
  #your comparison will depend on the field type but a quick Google search for
  #python type comparisons should help you out of all binds
  #if you really really need to, you can assign field values to variables and compare
    comparisonCounter += 1 #incremented in the if block
  rowCounter += 1 #incremented on the iteration
print (comparisonCounter\rowCounter * 100) #get your % and print it
```